# Clean field output in Views templates

Tags: drupal, templates, view

I'm trying to get clean output of fields in order to obtain semantic code.
In the default template generated by the Views module the snippet which outputs the field is:

```
<?php print $field->content; ?>
```

But a lot of markup is generated along with the value of the field.
Is there a way to get the field value directly?

I'm using Drupal 7, It seems like the old method:

```
$fields['field_name']->content;
```

is not functioning anymore.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) is a great module which gives a great control over the views output markup. But I realized that my problem was related to the *field* markup.

I found a video tutorial. It helped me a lot and hope could help others too.
[Theming Fields video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxZQqgvJk3s).

Answer (score 0):

[Semantic views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) is the answer. But it is still in dev for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

To customize output of Views you'll need to edit appropriate Views templates. You can find templates in modules/views/theme directory. Copy the ones you need to your theme directory and edit to your liking. You can have custom templates for different views, check out "Advanced->Theme: Information" in View options to see what file names are recognized by Views module. You might need original view template for customized template to work. Be sure to press "Rescan template files" button in "Theme: Information" after adding new custom view templates or removing them.